# What causes GLSL recompilation of vertex shader based on state?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I am using the [`ARB_debug_output`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_debug_output.txt) extension. The driver gives me this warning:

> Program/shader state performance warning: Vertex shader in program 16 is being recompiled based on GL state.

So, I tried setting various GL state before I compile my shader, including:

- `GL_BLEND`
- `GL_CULL_FACE`
- `GL_DEPTH_TEST`
- polygon-offset
- blendfunc

...but it still recompiles upon first draw.

What are the typical pieces of state that could cause the driver to recompile a vertex shader?

Comment: "*But it still recompiles upon first draw.*" What do you mean "upon first draw"? Is it the first time you're rendering with that shader at all? "*I tried setting various GL state before I compile my shader*" No shader compiler/linker is going to assume that the OpenGL state at the time of compilation/linking accurately reflects the OpenGL state that will be present at the time of use. So it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, at first render. I want to avoid a re-compile at that time. And I expect the driver to not recompile if state at compile-time is the same as the state at render-time.

Comment: "*I expect the driver to not recompile if state at compile-time is the same as the state at render-time.*" You shouldn't expect that. Driver writers certainly don't expect it, so neither should you.

Comment: @NicolBolas Those same 'driver writers' also put in the performance warning, though. If the re-compile could not be avoided, the warning makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've run across this problem recently. It occurred that unbinding Vertex Array Objects caused this warning to appear. After deleting the lines with `glBindVertexArray(0)` the warning message disappeared.

Comment: Why does this fix the error? I encountered it after refactoring my shader code according to the Cherno's tutorials. The error is fired from the debug message callback system from OpenGL 4.3. Furthermore, the error also disappears if you call `glUseProgram(0)` before drawing so you don't need to delete the line with `glBindVertexArray(0)`.